# How to display and use all existing tags at my write-post-at-frontend-panel?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, front-end, publish, post-editor

I can write and publish posts from my frontend - everything is fine. You know the backend: write-post-style, right? There it lists all existing tags.

How can I display all existing tags at frontend and use it the same way, like in backend? Especially the function "click on one existing tag" and use it with the post, that I am currently writing?

By the way: I want to use tags from my custom-taxonomy called "wissen"...

Do you know a solution, how to use this function at frontend?

This is my code: (you can see, how i do now the tags and i hope the code is everything important [my real file is a lot more code])

The code at the beginning of my form-page:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    $title =  $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'wissen'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
    wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

    //POST THE POST
    do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

}
```

In my body:

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
    <textarea id="description"  name="description"></textarea>
    <textarea id="post_tags"  name="post_tags"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
    <input type="submit" value="Eintragen" id="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: What are you using for writing posts on the frontend?

Comment: In 10 minutes there is my code in the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
<?php
$taxonomies = array( 
    'wissen_tags'
);
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false
);

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies,$args);

if (count($terms) > 0):
i = 0;
    foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
        <div class="wissen_tag_list">
            <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="wissen_tags" class="wissen_tag_list_ckb" <?php if ( $i == 0 ) { ?>checked<?php } ?>>
            <label class="wissen_tag_list_ckbl">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
<?php
    $i++; endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

Of course if you have many tags you might consider a more dynamic approach, e.g. by ajaxifing a input; and not showing the complete list always.

note:
→ you probably have to make above code fit your criteria/parameters better, not sure if I caught them all correctly;
→ additionally, above code is for selecting a single term;

---

edit: for multiple selections

- change `type` to `checkbox`;
- and make `name` - respectively the according $_POST variable - an array;

`<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="wissen_tags[]" class="wissen_tag_list_ckb">`