# Frontend tagging for both default and custom post type in wordpress

Tags: front-end

Wordpress backend (post-editor-panel) offers such an excellent tagging tool wherein we can choose from already existing tags. Is it possible to bring this functionality to the frontend without fancy ajax. Just with some good ol php. All I need is just a list of tags to choose from in the frontend and save it. I will need the functionality for both post types, default wp post type as well as for custom-post-type.

There is one similar [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101852/how-to-display-and-use-all-existing-tags-at-my-write-post-at-frontend-panel) with an unaccepted answer. I tried to use the code in the suggested answer, but it is far from perfect and just returns empty radio-buttons. There is nothing on google on this topic, Please suggest the correction in the code. Thanks.

```
<?php
$taxonomies = array( 
    'wissen_tags'
);
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false
);

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies,$args);

if (count($terms) > 0):
$i = 0;
    foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
        <div class="wissen_tag_list">
            <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="wissen_tags" class="wissen_tag_list_ckb" <?php if ( $i == 0 ) { ?>checked<?php } ?>>
            <label class="wissen_tag_list_ckbl">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
<?php
    $i++; endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: @G.M. need help again, Your code works extremely well for normal-post-type but not for custom-post-type. On line 22, I changed the `wp_set_post_terms` to `wp set object terms`, this still allows me to save tags in normal-post-type but not in custom-post-type. Any inputs please. I have asked it as a new question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125572/term-tag-not-being-saved-for-custom-post-type)

Comment: I've updated the code also changing `wp_get_post_terms` to `wp_get_object_terms`. Try now.

Comment: @G.M. Still not saving the tags from the frontend, though it saves well in the backend while logged in as admin. If it matters, I have the code on single-research.php (single-template-for-custom-post-type) wrapped in a statement like this `if(is_user_logged_in()) { do_action('frontend_term_assignment_form');
}`. I noticed that you made changes in user capabilities, from `manage_options` to `edit_posts` so I tried changing it to others and also commenting it out. But the results are null. Could you please do an actual test and see it for yourself. Greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Notice: completely update code after OP update answer.

Assuming you want to update in front-end the taxonomy 'post_tag' (the standard tags) fro standard post and a taxonomy called 'research-sections' for a custom post type called 'research'.

Probably you have to put the form in both `single.php` and `single-research.php` and in both you have to some stuff... because is always better having a DRY code, and related to WP is always better keep templates clean, I suggest you to put all the functional code **in a plugin or in `functions.php`** and modify as less as possible the templates.

You need essentially 2 functions: one that output the form, another that saves data.

For the first you can create your own action, in this way in template only thing you need is a `do_action` call.

For the function that saves data you can hook a standard WP action, like init.

The code:

```
add_action('init', 'frontend_term_assignment');
add_action('frontend_term_assignment_form', 'frontend_term_assignment_form');

function frontend_term_assignment() {
  if (
    ! isset($_POST['term_assignment_post_id']) ||
    ! intval($_POST['term_assignment_post_id']) ||
    ! current_user_can('edit_posts', $_POST['term_assignment_post_id']) ||
    ! isset( $_POST['term_assignment_nonce'] ) ||
    ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['term_assignment_nonce'], 'frontend_term_assignment')
  ) return;
  $post = get_post( $_POST['term_assignment_post_id'] );
  $taxonomy = null;
  if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
    $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
  } elseif ( $post->post_type == 'research' )  {
    $taxonomy = 'research-sections';
  }
  if ( empty($taxonomy) || ! isset($_POST[$taxonomy]) ) return;
  $terms = $_POST[$taxonomy];
  wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $terms, $taxonomy, false);
}

function frontend_term_assignment_form() {
  $post = get_queried_object();
  if ( empty($post) || ! isset($post->ID) || ! current_user_can('edit_posts', $post->ID) ) return;
  $taxonomy = null;
  if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
    $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
  } elseif ( $post->post_type == 'research' )  {
    $taxonomy = 'research-sections';
  }
  if ( empty($taxonomy) ) return;
  $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
  $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false );
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
  $post_terms = (array)wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "ids") );
  if ( ! empty($terms) ) {
    echo '<form method="post" id="frontend_term_assignment_form">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . wp_create_nonce('frontend_term_assignment') . '" name="term_assignment_nonce">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $post->ID . '" name="term_assignment_post_id">';
    echo '<div class="' . $taxonomy . '_term_list"><ul>';
    foreach ($terms as $term ) {
      $checked = in_array($term->term_id, $post_terms) ? checked(1, 1, 0) : '';
      printf('<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="%s" name="%s[]"%s> ' . $term->name . '</label></li>', $term->slug, $taxonomy, $checked);
    }
    echo '</ul><input type="submit" value="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__('Save %s'), $tax_obj->label) ) . '" />';
    echo '</div></form>';
  }
}
```

I've added security check like check the current user capabilities and a nonce check.

Almost all work are done.

Now in the templates (both `single.php` and `single-research.php`) just add the do_action after your loop:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  ...Your loop code here ...
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
// Nothing else is required here!
do_action('frontend_term_assignment_form');
?>
```

That's all. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the response. yes I am trying to assign tags to single posts. I intend to wrap the solution code in `if (current_user_can('manage_options', $post->ID))` to deny access to others. Please allow me a few minutes to test your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code throws a Syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 3, which is `$post_id = isset($the_post->ID) $the_post->ID : 0;` ?

Comment: ,now it throws `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_term() in /home2/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/single.php on line 207`. any ideas?

Comment: Just so you know, eventually I aim to work with multiple tags. I was about to ask this later how to utilize this code for multiple tags. `<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="wissen_tags[]" class="wissen_tag_list_ckb">`

Comment: sorry, but it still throws a different error  `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home2/site/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2688`

Comment: I have tried the code on localhost and a live site, it throws the same error. I respect your time.